# Toggle chunk output using "details" HTML tag

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, blogdown

I'm writing some tutorials using blogdown. For a pedagogical reason, I want my students to think before seeing the solution. Here's my current code.

**Original**

````
---
title: "Toggle Chuck Output Using details Tag"
output: html_document
---

```{r calc, prompt=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
90 + 30
```

<details>
  <summary>Toggle output</summary>
```{r, ref.label='calc', echo=FALSE, prompt=TRUE}
```
</details>
````

Here's my attempt:

To avoid repeatedly writing the HTML tags, I think I need to define a function similar to ...

```
togglable <- function(label, summary = "Toggle output"){
  cat('<details>')
  cat(' <summary>', summary, '</summary>', sep = '')

  # Code to print output using 'ref.label' should go here.
  # The following doesn't work. 
  knitr::knit_print(knitr:::knit_code$get(label))

  cat('</details>')
}
```

.... then replace the `<detals>...</details>` block with a R code chunk similar to the following:

**Use case 1 (better)**

````
```{r usecase1, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
togglable(label = "calc")
```
````

I tried to make it work, but in vain.

One more thing. If possible, I'd like this `togglable()` function to override the chunk options so that I don't even need to write `echo=FALSE`, `results='asis'`, because the following chunk would look nicer.

**Use case 2 (best)**

````
```{r usecase2}
togglable(label = "calc")
```
````

In summary, I would like to ask the following questions.

1. How can I define this `togglable()` function so that it behaves  in the same way as the original `<detals>...</details>` block?
2. Is it possible that this function overrides the options (`echo` and `results` in particular) for the chunk where this function is called? If yes, how?
3. Alternatively, is there any other idea how to produce the result of the original code without repeatedly writing the HTML tags?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by a combination of the [chunk option `ref.label`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#code-chunk) (to reuse chunks), a [chunk hook](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#chunk-hooks) (to print the `<details>` tag) and a [option hook](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#option-hooks) (to change the chunk options when displaying the results.

````
---
title: "Toggle Chuck Output Using details Tag"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)

knit_hooks$set(showDetails = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (before) {
    return("<details>\n")
  } else {
    return("\n</details>")
  }
})

opts_hooks$set(showDetails = function(options) {
  if(options$showDetails) {
    options$echo = FALSE
    options$results = "asis"
  }
  return(options)
})
```
  
```{r calc, prompt=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
90 + 30
```


```{r, ref.label="calc", showDetails = TRUE}
```
````

How it works:

- The chunk hook is executed before and after each chunk where the option `showDetails` is not `NULL`. It prints (returns) the respective HTML.
- The option hook adjusts the other options (`echo` and `results`) for each chunk there `showDetails` is `TRUE`.

---

The code could be further improved by globally setting the options of the `calc` chunk, such that you do not have to repeat them for all other "show code only" chunks: add `opts_chunk$set(prompt = TRUE, eval = FALSE)` to the setup chunk and `options$eval = TRUE` to the option hook.

Besides, if you want `<detail>` tags by default whenever using `ref.label`, you could use `ref.label` as option hook:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)

opts_chunk$set(prompt = TRUE, eval = FALSE)

knit_hooks$set(showDetails = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (before) {
    return("<details>\n")
  } else {
    return("\n</details>")
  }
})

opts_hooks$set(ref.label = function(options) {
  options$echo = FALSE
  options$results = "asis"
  options$eval = TRUE
  options$showDetails = TRUE
  
  return(options)
})
```
  
```{r calc}
90 + 30
```


```{r, ref.label="calc"}
```
````

Comment: I just realized that this answer assumes that separating computation from outputting is an actual requirement (which is why reusing the chunk is necessary). But this might just be part of a XY problem in the question. In this case, an [output hook](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output-hooks) might be the better solution, not requiring to reuse the chunk. But on the other hand, this approach might also be beneficial because other text / chunks (e.g. containing explanations) can be added between the code and its output. Please let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer! I think I want to put some text between the problem and answer and so this approach would better suit my needs. That said, I'm having several concerns. (1) The style for the output is gone. Maybe I should add some HTML code to mimic the default output? (which should be straightforward I guess.) (2) I'm wondering how to extend the contents of "details" block because "Answer" may be followed by some comments sometimes, which should also be hidden. Please allow me to take some more time to absorb your suggestions fully.

Comment: Glad that I could help so far. Regarding (1): This is due to `results = "asis"`. You can remove `options$results = "asis"` from the option hook to get default formatting. I thought this was what you requested.  (2): Difficult … You could print the `</details>` only conditional on some option and then close the tag manually, like [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ClaudiusL/162a6c4db4701fbc47f204d49bc01c9c/raw/b1cd326bf94b6b73de84bf8ea3dde8b8851783fc/answer.rmd).

Comment: I just realized that unfortunately this answer generates invalid HTML (as pandoc wraps the `details` tags in `p` tags). Browsers seem to correct this silently, but if valid HTML is a criterion for you, this might be an issue. (I don't know any workaround.)

Comment: Oh, it's actually a great idea to manually close the details tag.... maybe I could include another code chunk in the "details" block easily, which is very useful. As for the second comment, never mind! (I looked into the source but I couldn't even find the issue myself.) Thank you!

Comment: I slightly modified my question (added #3) hoping that your answer looks more appropriate (because it is).